# Resolve ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I am developing a method with variatic arguments that starts from a template.

```
template<typename levelType, typename formatType, typename ... variadicParamsType> 
void ClogLogger::log(levelType level, formatType format, variadicParamsType... formatParams)
{
   string levelHeader = getLevelHeader(level);
   clog << levelHeader << fmt::format(format, formatParams...) << endl;
}
```

Now the error:

```
log(0, "{}", "foo_1") // Prints foo_1 
log(0, "{} {}", "foo_1", "foo_2") // Error, getting <int, const char * e, const char * format, const char * formatParams>
```

On the other hand I have this same method, but accepting also an exception:

```
template<typename levelType, class exceptionType, typename formatType, typename ... variadicParamsType> 
void log(levelType level, exceptionType e, formatType format, variadicParamsType ... formatParams)
{
   string levelHeader = getLevelHeader(level);
   clog << levelHeader << fmt::format(format, formatParams...) << endl;
   THROW_MYEXCEPTION(e.what());// A custom macro
}
```

And performing well:

```
exception e;
log(0, e, {}{}, "foo_1", "foo_2") // Now, work´s fine
```

UPDATE:

I seem to have found the problem, the template expansion produces an ambiguity in the case:

```
log(0, "{}{}" "foo_1", "foo_2")
```

That expands as:

```
<int level, const char * e, const char * format, const char * formatParams>
```

This causes an error when e.what() is launched.

Do you know how I can force the compiler to expand using the first method? The one that does not contain the exception.

Comment: `const std::exception&` should not be a template parameter.

Comment: It seems really weird to be calling a function like this *with* an exception. It should produce one.

Comment: Even when you trash `const std::exception&` from template parameter list, I think you will get ambiguity issue. Please provide [mcve] of your problem. You can start with this: https://godbolt.org/z/aGbdqoxeP

Comment: @tadman doesn't seem that odd to want to log a caught exception?

Comment: @AlanBirtles That would make sense, but what's confusing is the `THROW` call in the middle there. Is this just hooking around an exception, logging, and re-raising? If so, it's odd to call it just `log`. Maybe instead of an override a different name would remove ambiguity.

Comment: Removing `const std::exception&` from the template list [works for me](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rqYd445jY).

Comment: Why don't you rename the second to something like `error`? Does `levelType` actually need a to be in parameter list? If it is a fixed type not constructible from strings, moving the exception parameter to first position among arguments must help. Finally using `std::format_string<args...>` for `format` parameter checks correctness at compile-time, rather than runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template<typename levelType, class exceptionType, typename formatType,
         typename ... variadicParamsType> 
auto log(levelType level, const exceptionType& e, formatType format,
         variadicParamsType... formatParams)
  -> std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(decltype(e.what())*)>0)>
{
    std::string levelHeader = getLevelHeader(level);
    clog << levelHeader << fmt::format(format, formatParams...) << std::endl;
    THROW_MYEXCEPTION(e.what());// A custom macro
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3MW1sKhev)

The idea is to exclude the second overload from overload resolution unless `e` "looks like an exception", defined as "`e.what()` is a well-formed expression" (seeing as the body of the function relies on `e.what()` being available).

Comment: I have tried it and it works, the only problem is that it goes inside a class and writing in the headers and the implementation the same, I get an error: no declaration matches

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bTEdr7b97)

Comment: I finally got it! Seems like it's something compiler related (note I use c++14) on the web I've been able to get it to run correctly. It seems that I shouldn't separate the implementation from the headers. Thank you so much

Comment: [Works for me](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8cqz6jb1z) with C++14, too, once I stub out `fmt::format`